# Time-series databases MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, time-series

I've come from a SQL data store background and I'm familiar with the Microsoft frameworks such as Entity framework and MVC.

I'm interested in learning about databases better suited for time-series data, but not just the database technologies themselves (e.g. OpenTSDB, Apache Cassandra, MongoDB).  I'm wondering if there are frameworks which combine the approaches of an MVC style architecture with the retrieval of data from a database used to better store time-series data?

The closest example I've found is this:
http://www.drdobbs.com/database/mongodb-with-c-deep-dive/240152181